# How to get value from CS file Method from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have UserControl. It is of Calendar. Now I want to call function of `CS` file in JavaScript which will return value.

Here is my cade:

```
//cs method
public string getCalendarData()
{
    return "[{\"id\":\"35424af8-4fd2-e611-8104-c4346bac5238\",\"title\":\"NanjitestCall1\",\"start\":\"2017-01-12 00:00:00\",\"allDay\":false,\"end\":\"2017-01-12 07:29:00\",\"backgroundColor\":\"#8224e3\",\"url\":\"?detail-phonecall&id=35424af8-4fd2-e611-8104-c4346bac5238\"}]
}

//ascx page
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //loading start
    var el2 = jQuery("#calendar");
    App.blockUI(el2);
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy'); // destroy the calendar
    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({//re-initialize the calendar
        disableDragging: true,
        disableResizing: true,
        defaultView: 'month',
        slotMinutes: 15,
        minTime: 8,
        header: h,
        editable: true,
        lazyFetching: true,
        timeFormat: 'h(:mm) t - ', // uppercase H for 24-hour clock,lowercase h for 12-hour clock
        viewDisplay: function (view) {
            //App.blockUI(el2);
        },
        events: //call function in .cs file and return value

        //function call in PHP
        //events: {
        //    url: '<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__); ?>' + "json_events.php?scp_sugar_object=<?php echo get_option('dynamic_conn_object'); ?>&scp_user_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['scp_user_id']; ?>",
        //    success: function (data) {
        //        App.unblockUI(el2);   //loading stop
        //    }
        //}
});
</script>
```

Can anybody please suggest me referent or hint to get this work?

Comment: You cannot call a .cs file directly in javascript. You need a "middle man" of sorts; be that an .aspx page as directed in one of the answers; using MVC in which case you call an Action method in a .cs file via the Controller; or you use the WebAPI framework. Otherwise you're on to plums!

Comment: Actually, I am working on DNN. So .aspx name can be never fix. It depends on user. If user create a page with name `test`, it will be changed. This is the reason why I am not using reference of `.aspx`

Comment: Then you create a handler, a page, a something that doesn't change. Sometimes things have to be fixed in time so that everyone knows they are available to be used. Maybe then your best bet is to create a generic handler that can easily be called and will not change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery AJAX to call the C# code which fetches the data value.

**C# code to get date from your user control:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetDateValue()
{
    //string date = [logic to fetch date from user control]
    return date;
}
```

**jQuery AJAX code to get the date value from C#:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<your aspx page>.aspx/GetDateValue",
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Date value: " + result);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not solution I wanted. In my case .aspx is not fixed. So, I can't go on the base of URL. Please guide me if any other way.

Comment: May be you can create an aspx page and use that to fetch the date value from another .cs file. To fetch value from cs file in JavaScript you definitely need to make an AJAX call. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Thanks but I can't use reference of aspx. Let me know if any other way.

Comment: Actually, I am working on DNN. So .aspx name can be never fix. It depends on user. If user create a page with name `test`, it will be changed. This is the reason why I am not using reference of `.aspx`